# Capture and change all logging message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, nlog, serilog

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 application. There are some log providers that I have as from box. Other words I cannot configure theese providers. But I need to add additional info to every logging message.

For example, code invoke:

`logger.LogInfo("Hello World");`

But logging provider must get, for example "UserId: 123; Hello World"

How can I reach this goal?

Comment: `Adapter` pattern can help https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter/csharp/example

Comment: Where does the additional text come from? Most logging frameworks allow to provide some custom formatting of log messages.

Comment: @KlausGütter
Additional info comes from domain info.
My "black box" logging providers don't expose any settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @nozd, by default it is not possible to achieve your requirement, you need custom the log extension to achieve. Besides, what is your UserId here? Do you use Identity or any other authentication?

Answer (score 0):

you can create an extension method for this like this,

```
public static class LogExtensions
{
    public static void CustomLogInformation(this ILogger log, string message)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"prefix{message}");
    }
}
```

you could also pass `Exception exception` as a parameter if you require it.

In this example, `prefix` is added, but you can change the value as per your requirements.

If the prefix values changes then you can pass that as well by adding one more parameter to this method. If it's the same for all scenarios then you can define it in some config file.

and if you look at the source code, `LogInformation` itself is an extension method.

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
{
    public static class LoggerExtensions
    {

        public static void LogInformation(this ILogger logger, string message, params object[] args)
        {
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, message, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[NLog Layout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layouts) enables you to capture additional [NLog Context](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context) besides what is provided with the actual logevent.

You could update your NLog Target Layout to include [${aspnet-user-identity}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetUserIdentity-layout-renderer) in the output:

```xml
<target xsi:type="console"
        name="console"
        layout="${aspnet-user-identity} ${level} ${message}" />
```

Another alternative could be [${aspnet-user-claim:ClaimTypes.Name}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-User-Claim-layout-renderer). If your user-information comes from custom location, then you can also implement a [custom layout-renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer).

Comment: My goal is to change log message for all providers including that come with my "black-box" library. NLogLayout approach can change log only in the own targets.

Comment: @nozd Then you should probably for making custom extension methods for [ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger)-interface, that adds extra context before calling [ILogger.Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.log)-method.